# Capture native STDOUT writes in Java code

Tags: java, stream, stdout, native-code

I'm writing a JUnit test case which invokes code that ultimately results in a `native` function call being invoked. Here's pseudocode of the test I want to write:

```
@Test
public void testNoWritesToStdOut() {
    x = new StdOutTrap();
    x.startTrappingStdOut();
    try {
        callTheFunctionUnderTest(); // Nothing should be written to stdout
        assertEquals("", x.capturedOutput());
    } finally {
        x.stopTrappingStdOut();
    }
}
```

Noting that `callTheFuntionUnderTest()` invokes `native` code which might be C code, as in:

```
...
printf("fail\n");
```

Or C++ code, as in:

```
...
std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
```

For clarity, I don't want to redirect calls to `System.out.X` to a custom `PrintStream` via `System.setOut`. I want to get a copy of the bytes, if any, which were written to the `stdout` standard stream during the execution of a `native` call over which I have no control.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture output from native code, you cannot do this in the JVM alone but need the operating system to help you.

You must invoke your test in a separate JVM and you must ask the operating system to capture the output for you.  The usual way of running a process in a shell might be what you need.